# Flutter - adding dependency to a package does not resolve dependency issue during the app compilation

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have just created my first flutter package. It has just dart code, so it is quite basic. However, I use one external dependency in my package to [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).
Since I don't use any of the provider classes outside the package, my understanding is, I should not need to add `provider` package dependency to the application, hence I might keep the dependency within my package only.
When I try to compile the app, however, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'provider' in 'package:provider/provider.dart'.
file:///local_path/lib/scale_widget.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'package:provider/provider.dart'
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```

Despite the fact, that `provider` package is imported inside my package. If I add `provider` dependency to my app, everything compiles.

Comment: Figure anything out on this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, actually, I ended up by adding the dependency to the app itself.

Comment: I have no idea why, but for me this was caused by an actual dependency issue with hosting app...  I resolved that and everything was okay.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem with **path_provider** package.

> Error: Could not resolve the package ‘path_provider’ in ‘package:path_provider/path_provider.dart’.

> Error: Not found: ‘package:path_provider/path_provider.dart’
> import ‘package:path_provider/path_provider.dart’;

**I was able to fix it by following commands:**

```
1. flutter upgrade 
2. flutter pub cache repair
3. flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Probably the problem was fixed already by flutter upgrade but i want to leave all the steps i did just in case.
Ps. In my case this was update from Flutter 2.0.6 to 2.2.1 .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dependencies are under "dependencies:" and not "dev_dependencies:" in your custom package pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Stop your application and Run it again. Also, make sure that you'd inserted your provider in dependencies and not in dev_dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try running Pub get after adding the dependency, then stop your app and run it again instead of using Hot Restart. This worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run:

```
flutter pub add provider
```